# How to add a UICollectionView to a Swift view model with an image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I'm not sure I'm approaching this correctly and would really appreciate some guidance.

I have an IOS Swift application that I'm trying to create a view for that has an image on the top 1/3 of the screen and then I'd like to add a UICollectionView to display events from the calendar in the bottom 2/3 of the screen.  Basically, it's an app that will allow the user to create/edit events to be notified when it's time to do something.  So, I created my View, dragged a UIImage control on the view, created the constraints, etc.  Then I dropped the UICollectionView on the view, created the constraints, etc.  All of the samples that I can find all derive the backing ViewModel from UICollectionView, is this required or can I populate the UICollectionView without having to derive from it?

Thanks in advance for any help with this design.

Comment: To clarify, your question is related to how to handle the data for a UICollectionView?

Comment: Sure, you can add a UICollectionView as a subview to another view... just search for `uicollectionview as subview`.

Comment: Kind of, I'm wondering is this the best approach for design.  Should I derive my backing ViewModel from UICollectionView or do I add a subview like DonMag suggested and then populate the UICollectionView with data like ryantxr is asking.

Comment: While you can add a collection view to the view controller and implement the collection view data source and delegate within that view controller, It's easier to use a collection view controller in the storyboard, subclass UICollectionViewController (with delegate and data source methods), and then implement your top image view as a section header cell within the collection view. Same with table views.

Comment: Thanks FryAnEgg, I was looking at the header for the UICollectionViewController and it looks like it will scroll up if I have a lot of events, I'd like to have the image be static at the top and if scrolling is necessary, it would just scroll the items in the collection view.  I haven't tried it yet but from what I could find, it looks like it's the behavior.